# need to generate a excel sheet in asp.net mvc,model properties should be the column headers, data validations must be applied through model only

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
public class CollegeModel
{
    [Display(Name = "College ID")]
    
    public int CollegeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "College Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "College Name is required")]
    public string CollegeName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Address cannot exceed 250 characters")]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Number of Departments")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number of Departments is required")]
    [Range(1, 100, ErrorMessage = "Number of Departments must be between 1 and 100")]
    public int NumberOfDepartments { get; set; }
}
```

This is the model class, I need those required fields should work in excel.
Properties should be the column headers, based on the model an excel sheet should be generated or download, after that when a user try to enter data in excel sheet, it should be validated according to the model and should display those errorMessage if anything gave wrong data.

```
public IActionResult ExcelStudent()
    {
       


            var headerValidation = worksheet.Row(1).Style.Protection.SetLocked(true);

            //unique coede for student id
            var StudentIdValidation = worksheet.Column(1).SetDataValidation();
            StudentIdValidation.Custom("=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=A1), --(A:A<>\" \"), --(A:A<>\"\"))                  <2");
            StudentIdValidation.IgnoreBlanks = false;
            StudentIdValidation.ErrorTitle = "Error at student id";
            StudentIdValidation.ErrorMessage = "no duplicate values";
            StudentIdValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;

            //required feild for student name
            var StudentNameValidation = worksheet.Column(2).SetDataValidation();
            StudentNameValidation.Custom("=IF(TRIM(A1)<>\"\", AND(SUM(--(B1:B1<>\"\"))>0, SUM(--(TRIM(B1:B1)<>\"\"))>0), TRUE)\r\n");
            StudentNameValidation.IgnoreBlanks = false;
            StudentNameValidation.ErrorTitle = "Error at student name";
            StudentNameValidation.ErrorMessage = "This field is required";
            StudentNameValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;

            //required feild and age validation
            var AgeValidation = worksheet.Column(3).SetDataValidation();
            AgeValidation.Custom("= IF(TRIM(A1) <>\"\", AND(ISNUMBER(C1), C1>=18, C1<=24, SUM(--(C1:C1<>\"\"), --(TRIM(C1:C1)<>\"\"))>0), TRUE)");
            AgeValidation.IgnoreBlanks = false;
            AgeValidation.ErrorTitle = "Error at age";
            AgeValidation.ErrorMessage = "This feild is required or Age should be between 18 and 24";
            AgeValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;

            // required feild and branch name validation
            var BranchNameValidation = worksheet.Column(4).SetDataValidation();
            BranchNameValidation.Custom("=IF(TRIM(A1)<>\"\", AND(SUM(--(D1:D1<>\"\"))>0, SUM(--(TRIM(D1:D1)<>\"\"))>0, LEN(D1)<=50), TRUE)\r\n");
            BranchNameValidation.IgnoreBlanks = false;
            BranchNameValidation.ErrorTitle = "Error at branch name";
            BranchNameValidation.ErrorMessage = "This feild is required or Branch name should not be more than 50 characters";
            BranchNameValidation.ShowErrorMessage = true;
```

---

This I have done but I gave custom formula in the controller, but without giving validations in controller the excel should be generated based on the model reqirements.